# cannot find libcrypto.so.1.0.0 src rpm

Tags: linux, python, rpm

I'm required to install python-requests using RPM's. 
I've downloaded:

```
python-requests
python-py
python-cryptography
python-pyOpenSSL
```

and unfortunately the SLES zypper tool is advising that `libcrypto.so.1.0.0` is also required, however I can't find on pbone or rpm find `libcrypto*SLE_11_SP3/x86_64.src.rpm`

*libopenssl* provides the *libcrypto* library

Comment: the answer is in your question: libopenssl provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0; whence there is no use looking for libcrypto*src.rpm .... just install libopenssl...

Comment: or search for libopenssl.***.rpm

Comment: You're right, and basically I'm in dependency hell, I have libcrypto.so.0.9.8 but not libcrypto.so.1.0.0 so now I will need an instance of SLES outside of the firewall to fix the dependencies for me. I need to get the company to open a firewall to the official repos. :( Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is in your question: libopenssl provides libcrypto.so.1.0.0; whence there is no use looking for libcrypto*src.rpm .... You have several possibilities:

1. add repositories that contain libopenssl (with version >= 1.0.0) and run your installation again. Note that this will update libopenssl; so all packages that depend on libcrypto.so.0 will complain about you updating, or will be updated.
2. search yourself online for all the rpms you need; and download them --> very time consuming!
3. search for older python-requests, python-py, python-cryptography, python-pyOpenSSL that requires libcrypto.so.0

Comment: About the deleted post : SLES 11 is a propitiatory OS. The license includes support. So the usual approach is to "ask Suse". And you can see for yourself how complex it is to change  libopenssl version : The post by @Chris Maes -